# On Solaris 7 Box trying to get X Record Extension Library to work using x11vnc

Tags: x11, solaris, x-server

Does Xsun support this extension?  Im on a Solaris Sparc Ultra 2 SunOs 5.7. x11vnc version: 0.9.9

Comment: Supported extensions are displayed with the `/usr/openwin/bin/xdpyinfo` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Support for the Record extension was added to Xsun in Solaris 7 11/99 as part of the upgrade from X11R6.0 to X11R6.4 - it wasn't available in prior versions of Solaris 7 (though once 11/99 was released, you could apply the patches to add it to Xsun).   As jlliagre said above, the xdpyinfo command should list the available extensions, as well as the X server version.